# What's wrong with my array of pointers to arrays of pointers to structs?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, tree

A short explanation, what I want to do: I want to build a hierarchical tree of data elements represented by structs. these elements shall be double linked so I can walk. I do not want to use dynamic allocation because the structure of the tree will not change at runtime.

```
struct menu {
  uint8_t type;  // typ des Menüpunkts
  struct menu * parent; // Pointer auf den übergeordneten MP
  struct menu *(*children)[]; // Pointer auf untergeordnete MP
  };  

struct menu *(*menll[5])[]; // auxillary array

struct menu gl_menlist[5]=
{
  {0,0,menll[0]}, 
  {0,0,menll[1]},
  {0,0,menll[2]},
  {0,0,menll[3]},
  {0,0,menll[4]}
};

struct menu * rxakvt01[]= {&gl_menlist[3], &gl_menlist[4]}; 

menll[0]=&rxakvt01;
```

Code fails at last line with this error message:

```
In file included from Dis0_10.ino:6: var/folders/jl/nv1qvh6n569cxq9xxfd6dx980000gn/T/build753942546562757431.tmp/initialisation.h:71: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token
```

After moving the initialisations of the vars and arrays to a function code, I have a new error message; much more meaningful though:

```
/[path_truncated]/initialisation.cpp: In function 'void shit()':
/[path_truncated]/initialisation.cpp:46: error: cannot convert 'menu* (*)[2]' to 'menu* (*)[]' in assignment
```

Comment: That's the first C compiler error I've seen referring to constructors and destructors. Sure this isn't C++?

Comment: Wha, what is that: `struct menu *(*menll[5])[];` ?

Comment: It is a c++ compiler. Unfortunately I can't change it. Last time I asked a similar question I tagged it with C++, then I got whacked about asking for c solutions under a c++ tag.

Comment: @2501: It is an array of pointers to arrays of pointers to struct menu.

Comment: @2501: I try to fill this array with pointers to arrays of pointers in the last two lines.

Comment: @Ariser That looks way to complicated for any purpose. Also that code shouldn't be in a header.

Comment: @2501: I'm open for suggestions. If I used C++ language elements, I created a class with a member vector for the children or something similar, and I was fine. But I'm stuck to C here.

Comment: "*...  I got whacked about asking for c solutions under a c++ tag*" that's odd, if using a C++ compiler it stays a C++ issue ... sry.

Comment: ok. changed the tag to c++

Comment: @Ariser you are stuck writing C, but also stuck compiling with a C++ compiler?

Comment: @crashmstr: Ok, the long explanation. This is code for an arduino. Arduino IDE uses avr-gcc. But my boss wants only C compatible code to work with. (certain arduino libraries exempt)

Comment: this does not seem as an argument against using dynamic memory `I do not want to use dynamic allocation because the structure of the tree will not change at runtime.` you need to allocate the memory somehow and the penalty will be either when loading the program or while running the program

Comment: probably good to use a few typedefs to make it readable.

Comment: ok, can I profit from dynamic allocation in this case? My computer has 2KiB of RAM.

Comment: what exactly is it you want to achieve? you have some menu hierarchy you want model ?

Comment: I was hoping to keep some arrays in flash if I never modify them after initialisation. Of course I will have to spend some const keywords.

Comment: Where is your code located? in a header? Just move it to a function scope and it works.

Comment: Yes it is a menu structure, in reality struct menu has more members which I removed for readability.

Comment: @2501: moved the code to a function. the error message is now much more meaningful. see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely, the failure to convert `menu *(*)[2]` to `menu *(*)[]` is a compiler shortcoming.

If the size of your submenus need not be dynamic, then simply declare

```
struct menu *(*children)[2];
```

and

```
struct menu *(*menll[5])[2];
```

and you should be fine.

If you need dynamic menu sizes, you would need to know the length of the submenus at some point, and this is something the compiler won't derive for you, so some sort of sentinel is advised to indicate the end of a submenu.

I found another thing that might not be what you intendet here. The definition of `gl_menlist` contains the values of `menll` at the time of definition, a later assignment won't change that. Here's what should work:

```
struct menu {
    uint8_t type;  // typ des Menüpunkts
    struct menu * parent; // Pointer auf den übergeordneten MP
    struct menu ***children; // Pointer auf untergeordnete MP
};

struct menu *(*menll[5]);

struct menu gl_menlist[5] =
{
    { 0, 0, &menll[0] },
    { 0, 0, &menll[1] },
    { 0, 0, &menll[2] },
    { 0, 0, &menll[3] },
    { 0, 0, &menll[4] }
};

struct menu *rxakvt01[] = { &gl_menlist[2], 0 };
struct menu *rxakvt02[] = { &gl_menlist[3], &gl_menlist[4], 0 };

menll[0] = rxakvt01;
menll[1] = rxakvt02;
```

Comment: As the number of submenus differ from menu to menu, I need dynamic menu sizes. I made a typecast: `menll[0]=(menu* (*)[])&rxakvt01;` and it seems to work (I have other errors to work out first), but this is no good programming practice, isnt't it? The second thing you found is a real show stopper. Thanks.